# how can i redirect url to specific page using struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, struts2

I have many destinations (say 150+) and each destination has 2 different variants:

- A
- B

I have generated a html for each of these variants. For e.g.:

- NewYork-A.html
- NewYork-B.html
- SanFrancisco-A.html
- SanFrancisco-B.html
- LasVegas-A.html
- LasVegas-B.html
  ...

generic format being:

- Destination-A.html
- Destination-B.html

each of these files are written to `/seo/Destination/`

How can I map a given URL to these files in struts 2:

`www.mysite.com/NewYork-Tourism` => **www.mysite.com/seo/Destinations/NewYork-A.html** AND
`www.mysite.com/NewYork-Travel` => **www.mysite.com/seo/Destinations/NewYork-B.html**

Generic:

`www.mysite.com/Destination-Tourism` => **www.mysite.com/seo/Destinations/Destination-A.html**

AND

`www.mysite.com/Destination-Travel` => **www.mysite.com/seo/Destinations/Destination-B.html**

---

One way I can think of doing this is generating as many actions as (destination * variant_types) and then map the result of each of those to the proper html files. Something like this:

```
<action name="NewYork-Tourism">
    <result name="success">/seo//Destination/NewYork-A.html</result>
</action>
<action name="NewYork-Travel">
    <result name="success">/seo//Destination/NewYork-B.html</result>
</action>
```

.. and so on

Is there any other (better) way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One qquick way which seems to me is to make use of Wildcard Mapping,Struts2 has a way namely Wildcard which seems more suitable to you.

> As an application grows in size, so will the number of action mappings. Wildcards can be used to combine similar mappings into one more generic mapping.

something like

```
<action name="List*s" class="actions.List{1}s">
  <result>list{1}s.jsp</result>
</action>
```

For more details please refer to the documents

- [wildcard-mappings](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/wildcard-mappings.html)

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this other than making as many actions ?

Comment: what actions?? if you do not specific class name S2 will create a default action for you OOB

Answer (score 0):

It can also do the other way, on the method public String execute() on your action class you are going to have nested if else. For example the first if statement is for New York and the user selected Tourism , you will return a value "New-York-Tourism"

Which in the case in our struts.xml

```
<action name="Destinations" method="execute" class="Your Class Location">
<result name="New-York-Tourism">/seo//Destination/NewYork-Tourism.html</result>
<result name="New-York-Travel">/seo//Destination/NewYork-Travel.html</result>
. . . . . .
```